# tmutil listbackups not working but Time Machine is

Tags: terminal, backup, time-machine

Time Machine disk is mounted and a backup is running:

```
$ tmutil status 
Backup session status:
{
    BackupPhase = Copying;
    ClientID = "com.apple.backupd";
    DateOfStateChange = "2022-10-21 07:39:32 +0000";
    DestinationID = "813D2FF7-900D-4ED5-A8A4-547F0B0DCBF1";
    DestinationMountPoint = "/Volumes/Time Machine Office";
    EventFractionOfTotalProgressBar = "0.1";
    Progress =     {
        Percent = "0.3645306849337138";
        TimeRemaining = "3410.983948796825";
        "_raw_Percent" = "0.3645306849337138";
        "_raw_totalBytes" = 863411830784;
        bytes = 10501558272;
        files = 33325;
        sizingFreePreflight = 1;
        totalBytes = 863411830784;
        totalFiles = 3462898;
    };
    Running = 1;
    Stopping = 0;
}
```

Volume is mounted and readable:

```
$ ls /Volumes/Time\ Machine\ Office/
2022-10-17-122159.previous    2022-10-17-130710.interrupted 2022-10-17-155850.interrupted 2022-10-19-084354.interrupted 2022-10-21-090343.inprogress  backup_manifest.plist
```

But I cannot get the list of backups:

```
$ tmutil listbackups 
No machine directory found for host.
```

This happens every three/four days. Rebooting or reconnecting the disk doesn’t seem to help, it just works again correctly after a while.

Any idea why `listbackups` is not working?

Comment: "This happens every three/four days" -> does this mean that it works for three days and then suddenly doesn't? And magically fixes itself a few hours later?

Comment: @nohillside exactly. It works, when executing the command I see the list. Then suddenly nothing. Rebooting, disconnecting the disk and reconnecting the disk, do not solve the problem. Then suddenly it works again.